# Clustering plots points into groups based on their elevation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, elevation, clustering

I have a plots shapefile for a region (polygon)converted to centroid points. I have added the geometry column to it  and also added elevation attribute to every point by sampling the plots vector file with a DEM raster which is also of the same region . Now I want these plots (centroid points)  to be grouped into clusters of same elevation or with a max variance of 3 meters in the elevation.If vertex points of the same plots have difference in their elevation greater than say 3m then i want to break the plot into two  and then clustering resumes . This will help in managing the data of plots and be vital in planning and administration

Is triangulation a solution to this?

The solution need not involve clustering.  If the input parameters get grouped according  to elevation then that is good too.

Comment: Does the solution have to involve clustering? Or would it be ok to just split the input features into groups every 3 meters?

Comment: @underdark yess will do.Pls guide me through it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need real clustering and can live with simply splitting the input features into classes every 3 meters, use the following two steps:

1. create a class field:

[image]

2. split the layer using the class field:

[image]